# Representing a number

Tags: binary

I have a number in base $10$. The number is $N$. $N=-127$. Assuming $16$ bit 2's complement number representation, I need to convert $N$ to hexadecimal

I am not sure how to proceed.  I know that the binary representation of $-127$ is $1000000001111111$. I am confused as to what the question is asking. Please help. Sorry for the tag.

Comment: Is the number given is the 2 's complement representation of some other number?

Comment: I've replaced the tag with `binary`. This isn't perfect given the tag description, but there doesn't appear to be any tag better suited to questions about $2$'s complements. (If there is a better tag, I would be pleased for the `binary` tag to be replaced.)

Comment: I forgot that there is a tag called binary sorry for that

Comment: I had no idea comments supported emoji now.

Comment: Good that u know now Travis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression for $-127$ is the sign-magnitude representation, not the [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation.  To get two's complement, you start with the representation for $+127$, which in $16$ bits is $0000\ 0000\ 0111\ 1111$.  To negate it you complement each bit, getting $1111\ 1111\ 1000\ 0000$ and add $1$ to get $1111\ 1111\ 1000\ 0001$.  Note that you can now add $127+(-127)$ and get $0$ if you ignore the carry out.  That is one of the nice things about two's complement.

To convert this to hex, you can just convert each set of four bits, so the hex representation is $FF81$

Comment: So basically in this question I had to find the 2's complement representation of the number and then convert that to hexadecimal. Thanks man for the answer . I was confused when I saw the question. An upvote and an accept.